# How to apply an already existing material to an object in Python?

Tags: python, materials, scripting

I've searched a bit and gotten close to the answer but I just can't figure it out. I just want to apply it to a context object.

Answer (score 1):

```
import bpy


material = bpy.data.materials['Material']
bpy.context.object.data.materials.append(material)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want material to be seen, you have to change object's **active_material**.

EDITED (thanks Markus for clarification):
If there is no material yet, this may be little bit too much (you have to update the layer) and it is perfectly ok to use answer by Karan. However if there was some material before assigned to the object, you use this solution.
You can also firstly add material do object's data materials and then set the active material. This approach is helpful when you have many objects and many materials and you want to keep in track with which materials are used in which objects.

```
import bpy

material = bpy.data.materials['Material']
bpy.context.object.active_material = material

# in some cases you have to update the view to see the material change
bpy.context.view_layer.update()
```

Comment: I don't understand the downvote here. This seems like it should answer the question in an alternative manner to the other answer ?

Comment: *"If you want material to be seen"* - the other answer will also make the material visible **if** there were no other materials assigned before.